# Are commuting elements in the Weyl algebra polynomials in one element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $P$ and $Q$ are commuting elements of the first Weyl algebra, over some field $k$, is it true that there exists an element $H$ in the Weyl algebra such that $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials in $H$ with coefficients from $k$?

I am nearly certain that this is not true but I have not found a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the first Weyl algebra $A=k\langle x,y \rangle/(yx-xy-1)$ over $k$ a field of characteristic $p$. Then $x^p$ and $y^p$ are central, so for example $x^py=yx^p$, but $x^p$ and $y$ do not satisfy the conditions as given.

Comment: Good example, but I have realized that I would really like to know the answer when the ground field has characteristic zero. Sorry about that. I will accept your answer and ask a new question.