# Commuting elements in Weyl algebras of characteristic zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic zero and $P$ and $Q$ are commuting elements of the first Weyl algebra. Is it true that $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials in a some third element $H$?

I asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209880/are-commuting-elements-in-the-weyl-algebra-polynomials-in-one-element) before but without the characteristic zero condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This counterexample is due to Dixmier, Proposition 5.5 of:

Dixmier, J. [Sur les algèbres de Weyl](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1968__96__209_0) *Bull. Soc. Math. France* **96** (1968) p. 209–242.

I learned about it from the early pages of

Makar-Limanov, L. [Centralizers in the quantum plane algebra](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-8176-4478-4_16?null) Studies in Lie Theory,
Progress in Mathematics Volume 243, (2006), p. 411-416.

Let 
$$U = (\partial^3 + x^2 - 1)^2 + 2 \partial$$
$$V = (\partial^3 + x^2 - 1)^3 + \frac{3}{2} \left(  (\partial^3 + x^2 - 1)^2  \partial +  \partial (\partial^3 + x^2 - 1)^2 \right).$$

Then 
$$UV=VU \quad \mbox{and} \quad V^2 = U^3 + 1.$$
Disclaimer: I have not checked these identities; I just copy-typed them.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $U=u(T)$ and $V=v(T)$ for some polynomials $U$ and $V$ and some differential operator $T$. Clearly $T$ is nonconstant. Then $T$ does not obey any polynomial relation within the Weyl algebra (exercise). So we must have
$$v(t)^2 = u(t)^3+1$$
as an equality of polynomials. We claim there are no nonconstant polynomials $u$ and $v$ obeying $v(t)^2 = u(t)^3+1$ (in characteristics not $2$ or $3$).

Conceptual proof: $v^2=u^3+1$ is a genus one curve, so it can't be algebraically parametrized by a genus zero curve.

Direct proof: Since $0^2 \neq 0^3+1$, $u$ and $v$ have no common zeros. Taking derivatives of both sides, we have
$$2 v v' = 3 u^2 u'.$$
So every zero of $v$ is also a zero of $u'$ (with multiplicity), and we deduce that $\deg v \leq \deg u -1$. But also, every zero of $u$ is a zero of $v'$ (twice, in fact) so $\deg u \leq \deg v-1$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I had actually read these articles at an earlier point but clearly part of them had slipped my mind.

Comment: Please, what if we further require that $P$ has a 'Dixmier mate', namely, there exists $R$ such that $[P,R]=1$? (=$P$ is nilpotent).

Comment: @user237522 It is an open problem whether or not every endomorphism of the Weil algebra is an automorphism https://math.stackexchange.com/q/656415/448 . With $P$ and $R$ in your comment, the map $t \to P$, $\partial \to R$ is an endomorphism. If it is an automorphism, then the centralizer of $P$ is $k[P]$, since the centralizer of $t$ is $k[t]$. If the Weyl algebra has non-invertible endomorphisms, then I don't know what happens.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5202 answers my comment (with $H=P$).

Answer (score 0):

However, the $(1,1)$-leading term of each of your given $P$ and $Q$ is a power of the some $(1,1)$-homogeneous element $R$:
$l_{1,1}(P)=\lambda R^n$ and $l_{1,1}(Q)=\mu R^m$,
$\lambda,\mu \in k^*$; just apply [Theorem 1.22 (2)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51959382_The_Dixmier_conjecture_and_the_shape_of_possible_counterexamples_II)

Notice that you can add to your original question "each of $P$ and $Q$ is homogeneous of some degree" and get a positive answer to your question.